# How to force keyboard with numbers in mobile website in Android

Tags: android, html, webview, keyboard, html-input

I have a mobile website and it has some HTML `input` elements in it, like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="txtAccessoryCost" size="6" />
```

I have embedded the site into a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for possible Android 2.1 consumption, so that it will also be an Android application.

Is it possible to get the keyboard with numbers instead of the default one with letters when this HTML `input` element is focused?

Or, is it possible to set it for the whole application (maybe something in [the Manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)), if it is not feasible for an HTML element?

Comment: If want a numeric keypad on iOS in addition to Android, you should do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31619311/806956

Comment: The `inputmode="number"` attribute seems like the correct answer in late 2019: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode.  The highest voted answer at the time of this comment suggests `type="number"`, which comes with some of its own pitfalls; `inputmode` appears to only impact the virtual keyboard display, rather than the behavior/constraints of the input itself.

Answer (score 125):

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

Both of these present the numeric keypad when the input gains focus.

`<input type="search" />`
shows a normal keyboard with an extra search button

Everything else seems to bring up the standard keyboard.

Comment: Will take a look at it today, and then will let you know if that would work. Thank you, Richard!

Comment: Hi Richard. None worked, input field is still opening the standard keyboard.

Comment: [The HTML specification’s list of `input` `type`s](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html), including [`number`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) and [`tel`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#telephone-state-%28type=tel%29).

Comment: Note that [the keyboard for `type="tel"` is worse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box#comment26774412_15283380) for typing numbers than the keyboard for `type="number"`.

Comment: `<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />` [also brings up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15283380/578288) the numeric keyboard, but only on iOS, [not on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-inputs-spin-box#comment26774412_15283380).

Comment: `type="number"` alone misses browsers in mobile devices.  You must include `inputmode="numeric"` as well.  See post by @Reza.

Answer (score 53):

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I am posting this as an answer, not a comment, as it is rather important info and it will attract more attention in this format.

As other fellows pointed, you can force a device to show you a numeric keyboard with `type="number"` / `type="tel"`, but I must emphasize that **you have to be extremely cautious with this.**

If someone expects a number beginning with zeros, such as `000222`, then she is likely to have trouble, as some browsers (desktop Chrome, for instance) will send to the server `222`, which is not what she wants.

About `type="tel"` I can't say anything similar but personally I do not use it, as its behavior on different telephones can vary. I have confined myself to the simple `pattern="[0-9]*"` which do not work in Android

Comment: The automatic reformatting probably does not happen with `type="tel"`. [The spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#telephone-state-%28type=tel%29) notes that `tel` doesn’t enforce any particular syntax, unlike [`number`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), which requires that its value be a [valid floating-point number](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number).

Comment: How bad is it? We're trying to speedup the form process for our mobile customers and this seems like an obvious solution, but we also want something reliable. You posted a strong warning against using this method. I wonder if you could elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: @Philll_t, a user needs to send '000222' data, but you on the server side get '222' instead. Don't you see that functionality is completely broken? The server gets wrong data.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but what I'm saying is that: what percentage of users see this? Is this a problem on major mobile browsers such as Safari and Chrome? How do you know this is a problem, is there a link you can provide. I believe you, I just want to research myself and haven't seen anything suggesting this, maybe you can point me on the right direction. We're just trying to see if our customer base will not benefit from this.

Comment: @Philll_t I think the best example for this warning is for Date of Birth input fields. Where you need to input manually the day, month and year. And yes, there's still a lot of websites uses this style instead of the commonly used date pickers. Regarding the problem on Date of Birth input fields, is when you input your Day or Month starting with "0", e.g. 08.

Comment: `type=number` seems to be a good solution but it is not when those up-down-arrows appear on the input field using desktop browsers. Lucky us we can hide those arrows now with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22306944/1066234 -- PS: And then you run into the next problem using `type=number` https://stackoverflow.com/q/35315157/1066234

Answer (score 27):

`inputmode` according to [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#input-modalities:-the-inputmode-attribute) is the the default method.

For iOS devices adding `pattern` could also help.

For backward compatibility use `type` as well since Chrome use these as of version 66.

```
<input
  inputmode="numeric"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  type="number"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was looking for `decimal` and found it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Answer (score 9):

This should work. But I have same problems on an Android phone.

```
<input type="number" /> <input type="tel" />
```

I found out, that if I didn't include the jquerymobile-framework, the keypad showed correctly on the two types of fields.

<strike>But I havn't found a solution to solve that problem, if you really need to use jquerymobile.</strike>

**UPDATE:**
I found out, that if the form-tag is stored out of the

```
<div data-role="page">
```

The number keypad isn't shown. This must be a bug...

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. I'm not sure I understand though: "if the form-tag is stored out of the div[data-role=page]". In my case the problem occurs with forms that are nicely nested inside a div[data-role=page]. Perhaps the problem is that these pages are being displayed, in my case, as dialogs?

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers igoners sending leading zero to the server when the input type is "number". So I use a mixing of jquery and html to load a numeric keypad and also make sure that the value is sent as a text not as a number:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".numberonly").focus(function(){$(this).attr("type","number")});
$(".numberonly").blur(function(){$(this).attr("type","text")});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="numberonly">
```

Comment: This causes an annoying problem on Chrome for Android. When you tap on the input, the keyboard does **not** come up. You must then tap on the textbox a second time and then the keyboard does come up with the number-only keyboard. I really wish we had a `type="digits"` option so we didn't have to have these hacks. I mean, it's not like a zero-leading number is that rare (Zip Codes in the US are an obvious example).

Comment: I face the same problem too! setting field to "type=tel" is the best solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

For a Numeric Keyboard with **DECIMAL POINT**

```
<input inputmode="decimal" type="number" />
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, for me, this works with a litte modification.

`<input id="myfieldtext" inputmode="decimal" type="decimal" >`

When I use this, on Android, the field shows only number keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

Add a step attribute to the number input

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Source: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Answer (score -3):

`input type = number`

When you want to provide a number input, you can use the HTML5 input type="number" attribute value.

```
<input type="number" name="n" />
```

Here is the keyboard that comes up on iPhone 4:

iPhone Screenshot of HTML5 input type number
Android 2.2 uses this keyboard for type=number:

Android Screenshot of HTML5 input type number