# HTML Meta tag to get Android to use input type="tel" in form

Tags: android, html, mobile, meta, keypad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Force Keyboard with Numbers in Mobile Website in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372380/how-to-force-keyboard-with-numbers-in-mobile-website-in-android)

I had this working but forgot the exact meta tag. I am using:
    `<input type="tel">`
to get the number keypad to display when user enters their account number in the specified field but for some reason it is failing. I know there is a meta tag like `<meta "telephone=no">` or something that gets android to behave normally and allow the tel keypad to be used for input entries on web forms but cannot remember it. Anyone know the answer?

Comment: have you tried this `<input type="number" step="0.01">` ?

Comment: You should use `type=number` for an account number, not `type=tel`. And if you don’t get a numeric keypad, the reason is probably the use of some library or other code that disturbs the functionality (see answers to the duplicate).