# Open Android numeric keyboard programmatically

Tags: android

How can I open Android's numeric keyboard programmatically?

I know how to set the EditText to numeric and initiate numeric keyboard but I want a solution without EditText or Layout because I am trying to open the keyboard for Webview.

Comment: I guess it has to be done from the html of the web page. Or you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372380/how-to-force-keyboard-with-numbers-in-mobile-website-in-android)

Comment: @SripadRaj I tried to set .focus() in HTML Jquery but that did not open the keypad

Comment: Have you achieved what you wanted? I am also trying to do this for a custom view (which inherits View) but I am having no success :/

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
EditText etxt = new EditText(this);

etxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```