# Change keyboard to Numeric type on condition in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

So I'm running a webview and I want to change the keyboard to numeric on a form element if it is a Numeric Input, but I'm unable to do so. 
So is there any way to do it or it is not even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your webview try putting `<input type="number" .../>` and the keyboard should automatically change to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

Both of these present the numeric keypad when the input gains focus. Credit goes to Richard Kernahan over at [How to force keyboard with numbers in mobile website in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372380/how-to-force-keyboard-with-numbers-in-mobile-website-in-android). Cheers